# Handling foreign checks in Laravel 5 migrations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, database-migration

I have a `calls` table with `user_id` column and a foreign key constrain. So, user_id is related to `users` table.

I made a migration which deletes the column and foreign key constrain. The `up` method works fine. However, when it comes to `down` it breaks down because I add a user_id column and then restore the constrain, but the values in the column have nothing to do with real data so I got 150 MySQL error.

I've found a solution which didn't work for me. The solution is to temporarily disable foreign key constrains. Here is my migration file:

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

```
class RemoveUseridFromCalls extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('calls', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->dropForeign('calls_user_id_foreign');
            $table->dropColumn('user_id');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        \DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');

        Schema::table('calls', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('set null');
        });

        \DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');
    }

}
```

But I still get the same error.

So, the questions are:

1. What would you do if you need to remove `user_id` from columns table as it's not needed anymore, however you have to write the down method as well as up?
2. Why disabling foreign key checks doesn't work?

I use `InnoDB` as table type for all my tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `onDelete('cascade')`.

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('calls', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade'); // use 'cascade'
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('calls');
}
```

}

`onDelete('cascade')` tells Laravel to delete a  `calls` row when it's corresponsding foreign key `user_id` is deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I honestly don't get it, I already have a calls table and now I want to remove user_id from it. So in the up method I drop it, but I wasn't able to return in in the down method

Comment: You should definitely read their documentation on this for a full explanation: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations but I'll try to point you in the right direction.  First of all, you're overthinking this.  The `up()` method is for setting up a database table.  The `down()` method is for destroying a database table.  If you realized you'd like to change your database, simply run `php artisan migrate:reset` which will run first run the `down()` methods for each migration and then run the `up()` methods.  Note this will erase your entire database. If you like, we can open a conversation.

Comment: But what if I want to make a change to existing table? In this case just remove the user_id column? Considering that calls table are in production and I can't change the migration I've already pushed to git

Comment: If `calls` is already in production, you can create another migration file that alters `calls`.  It's in the documention I linked above.  Specifically, this section: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#modifying-columns

Comment: Yes, exactly. I made another file (remove_userid_from_calls.php), in my code above the class is called "RemoveUseridFromCalls". There I removed the user_id from table in the up method. Then, in order to test how rollback works I've tried "php artisan migrate:rollback" and got an error saying that if I add user_id back I got a foreign key constrain (150 errorno mysql). So I've disabled foreign key constrains and again get the error.

Comment: Read the documentation.  It's all there.  For example, there are no `up()` or `down()` methods for modifying existing tables.  Also, you'll have to add the doctrine/dbal dependency to your composer.json.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81711/discussion-between-raphael-rafatpanah-and-victor).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by separating migration into several files. First one creates the table, the others add columns for the keys and the keys themselves.

After that everything starts working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

To check foreign key in table while dealing with migration can be as follow:

```
$keyExists = DB::select(DB::raw('SHOW KEYS FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE Key_name=\'YOUR_FOREIGN_KEY_NAME\''));

if(!$keyExists){
    $table->foreign('app_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('apps')
         ->onDelete('cascade');
}
```